# Chain functions in CloudFormation ImportValue, Join and Ref

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I want to combine 3 functions in CloudFormation YAML but failing to do so.

I've got an exported parameter that I want to access `foo-exportedParam`
Then I want to import it, but taking into account that the prefix `foo` is dynamic and comes from a parameter in the template.

So I want something like

```
Name: Fn::ImportValue Fn::Join ['', [Fn::Ref prefix, "-exportedParam"]]
```

If I have the param `prefix = foo`, then this should translate into

```
Name: !ImportValue foo-exportedParam
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation gave me a clue on the syntax. This works

```
Name: 
  Fn::ImportValue:
    !Join ['', [!Ref prefix, "-exportedParam"]]
```

See nested simple sample: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html